# Neo4j: Shortest path between known start node and multiple end nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, dijkstra, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph with ~10000 nodes, I'm trying to find the longest path between a known start node and an unknown end node but of a known type Reader.

When I had 1000 nodes this computed fine in 4 seconds but now it is taking a long time, presumably because of the large list of possible end nodes.

I'm wondering if there is a better algorithm to do this, my only possible thought is to add some filtering to p2 to shorten the size of the list however this is not ideal as I would like to match a lot of edge cases.

```
MATCH (p1:Book{id: '0532013000'})-[r*1..5]-(p2:Reader) 
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight(
  p1, p2, 'REL_ONE|REL_TWO|REL_THREE|REL_FOUR', 'mean', 1) YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight
ORDER by weight DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Maybe you need to give a direction on your relationships to avoid loops.